# Get k-best dependency parse trees

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-parsing

For a project I need a dependency parse tree of a sentence. This works quite well using Stanford NLP:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
// ...
public void parse(String sentence) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse");
    Annotation document = new Annotation(sentence);
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    CoreMap firstSentence = sentences.get(0);
    SemanticGraph dependencies = firstSentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
    // ...
}
```

However I now also need other possible parse trees, i.e. the **k-best parse trees**. I can later pick out the tree that makes most sense. I have looked around but not found any code on the web that does this using a Java API.

Has anyone done something like this?

Cheers!

Comment: See similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014631/get-the-k-best-parses-of-a-sentence-with-stanford-parser

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though that question is about PCFG parses, not dependency parses.

Comment: Maybe you can use the constituency parse results as input to get the dependency parse trees given that Stanford Parser obtains the latter from the former. See "Generating Typed Dependency Parses from Phrase Structure Parses"