# Where can I get the CFG used in Stanford Parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to identify the key phrase(s) in a question along with the type of answer expected. I am using Stanford Parser to generate the parse tree of the question. I need to traverse this parse tree and make choices at each node whether it is a key phrase or not based on some heuristics.
If only I had access to the complete CFG used in Stanford Parser, I could expand the heuristics to cover all the children of a node that might appear in the tree.

[The Stanford Parser: A statistical parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)

Comment: This is a near-duplicate to my own question a few weeks ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023506/exporting-pcfg-from-stanford-lexicalized-parser. Unfortunately, we haven't seen an answer to that one either...

Answer (score 0):

Every trained [`LexicalizedParser`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html) instance has fields `bg` and `ug`, which are learned [`BinaryGrammar`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/BinaryGrammar.html) and [`UnaryGrammar`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/UnaryGrammar.html) instances. Each of these classes have methods which allow you to look up binary / unary rewrite rules from a given parent or child (or sibling, in the binary case). Every rewrite rule (see [`Rule` interface](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/Rule.html)) has an associated log-probability under the field `score`. You can use [`LexicalizedParser#stateIndex`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html#stateIndex) to get the necessary `int` IDs for any given tree constituent.

That being said, it's not clear that seeing all possible productions would be a good thing for your purposes. (The grammar is pretty ugly!)
You might do better [examining the *k*-best parses for a given sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071400/176075).